# What is the php code I need to add to this file in order to get an image to appear in this custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using a wordpress theme that has a custom post type called "link" which simply produces a post where the title links to an outside link you specify. It also includes some text in the body of the post. I would like to also be able to display an image. Right now it is not showing the image.

Here is the code:

```
elseif ( has_post_format( 'link' )) {
         if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_link_url', true)!=''){ 
            $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_format_link_url', true);
            }else{
            $link = ''; 
            }
        ?>
        <h2 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank" title="Follow this link">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a> 
        </h2>
        <p>
```

Is there anything I can add to make it display an image as well as text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere on this example where you are using an  tag to insert an image. The img tag has two required attributes, src and alt. Src is the path to your image, whereas alt is the alternate text for the image. So:

```
<img src="images/myImage.png" alt="This Is My Image"/>
```

Hope that helps!